# How to pass ID from React component to ASP.NET controller?

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building test CRUD application with React, ASP.NET and EF.

Right now I have a problem with sending `productID` to be deleted by the asp.net  controller from the server..

I want to send `projectID` from `handleDeleteProduct`. Right now `productID` argument in controller is getting no value. I am guessing that there is something wrong in `ProductBox`

`ProductList.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import Product from '../components/Product';

class ProductList extends React.Component {
    deleteProduct(productID) {
        this.props.onDelete(productID);
    }
    render() {
        let productNodes;
        if (this.props.data) {
            productNodes = (this.props.data || []).map(product => {
            return (
                <Product onDelete={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)} name={product.name} key={product.productID}>
                    {product.description} <span>, </span>
                    {product.price}
                </Product>
            );
        });
    }
        return (
            <div className="productList">
                {productNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ProductList;
```

My `ProductBox.js` looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import ProductList from '../components/ProductList';
import ProductForm from '../components/ProductForm';

class ProductBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: this.props.initialData };
        this.handleProductSubmit = this.handleProductSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleDeleteProduct = this.handleDeleteProduct.bind(this);
    }
    loadProductsFromServer() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ data: data });
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    handleProductSubmit(product) {
        const products = this.state.data;
        product.productID = products.length + 1;
        const newProducts = products.concat([product]);
        this.setState({ data: newProducts });

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('Name', product.Name);
        data.append('Description', product.Description);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadProductsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    handleDeleteProduct(projectID) {
        const data = projectID;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.deleteUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadProductsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.setInterval(() => this.loadProductsFromServer(), this.props.pollInterval);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="productBox">
                <h1>Tutaj React z EF</h1>
                <ProductForm onProductSubmit={this.handleProductSubmit} />
                <ProductList onDelete={this.handleDeleteProduct.bind(this)} data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ProductBox;
```

piece of code from `app.js` :

```
<ProductBox url="/comments" submitUrl="/comments/new" deleteUrl="/comments/delete" pollInterval={2000}/>
```

HomeController.cs

```
[Route("comments/delete")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteComment(int productID)
        {
            var products = _context.Products;
            foreach(var item in products)
            {
                if(item.ProductID == productID)
                {
                    products.Remove(item);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return Content("Success :)");
        }
```

Comment: Check what you are getting in   `const data = projectID;`

Comment: @Justcode maybe it will be stupid question, but how can I do it?

Comment: console.log(projectID);

Comment: @Justcode - undefined

Comment: Change `<Product onDelete={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)} ` to `<Product onDelete={(e)=>this.deleteProduct(product.productID)}`

Comment: @Justcode, it helped, because now I have from const data = projectID; integer. Now, the only problem is, that component did not pass the number to the controller.

Comment: You need to check with xhr request how to pass this id to the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first problem is you are not passing the productId to parent controller. Here is how you need to do it.

```
<Product onDelete={(e)=>this.deleteProduct(product.productID)}
```

Second, make sure in parent method `handleDeleteProduct` you are getting this productId Passed
Third, check for the xhr request is correct. Here is an example of it

```
handleDeleteProduct(projectID) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", this.props.deleteUrl, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
            // Request finished. Do processing here.
        }
    }
    xhr.send("productID=" + projectID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Partly you helped me to solve the problem. I found the final solution with $ajax

Comment: That's great! :)

Comment: I am trying now to figure out how to convert $ajax to fetch... I dont want to call whole jquery for this :/

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#example-using-ajax-results-to-set-local-state Here is an example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few hours of flatting my butt when trying to figure it out i found a solution. I used Ajax with jQuery:

```
handleDeleteProject(projectID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: './comments/delete',
            data: { productID: projectID },
            type: 'get',
            cache: true,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("ok");
            },
        });
    }
```

I start to think, that XMLHttpRequest is kind a crap.Thank you @Justcode for your time and effort.